# building distinct pairs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

```
productcode = ['apple','orange','melons'] # 1000+ more
pairs = []
count = 0
for xi,x in enumerate(productcode):
    del productcode[xi]
    for yi,y in enumerate(productcode):
        pc2 += 1
        p = (x,y)
        pairs.append(p)

print ("Number of distinct pairs:",pc2)
```

productcode contains over a thousand data items:

```
apple

orange

grape
```

Expected output:

```
apple orange

apple grape

orange grape
```

The nested for loops only iterate over half the items in the list (productcode) and therefore I end up with much lesser number of pairs than I expect. Could anyone help explain what I've done wrong, or what is actually happening?

Comment: Add desired input and output. What's `content`?

Comment: do not moidify when enumerating over something - just as a safeguard. and provide code as  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can copy your **m**inimal **e**xamplecode to **v**erify without need to add to it so it is **c**omplete (**out of order** - you get the gist of it).

Comment: you modify the enumeration while enumerating it ...

Comment: did one of the below answers help? if so, feel free to accept one, or ask questions to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modify a collection while iterating it. Bad idea.

There is this [cool datastructure that gets rid of duplicates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

**Create plenty of duplicate data:**

```
from itertools import combinations

# make all 2-length combinations of 1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,3   
comb = list(combinations([ 1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,3  ],2)) # works with strings as well
print(comb)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), 
 (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), 
 (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 3), 
 (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), 
 (2, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 3), (4, 5), (4, 3), (5, 3)]
```

**Make data unique:**

```
uniques = set(comb)
print(uniques)
```

Output:

```
set([(1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (4, 5), (3, 1), (1, 4), 
     (2, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 1), (4, 3), (2, 2), (2, 5), 
     (5, 3), (3, 4), (1, 1), (3, 5)])
```

If you need all [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of something, stuff the somethings into a `set` beforehand to eleminate all dupes and create your `combinations` via `itertools.combinations` from the `set`. If you use `combinations` on a `list` with dupes, you create unneeded many `combinations` - so **`set`** first, then **`combination`s** from it.

---

Drawback/catch for sets (and dicts) is that they need immutable keys - so `tuples` are fine, `lists` are not but `strings` work well. You can `tuple(alist)` if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is a natural choice for this. To avoid duplicates, just convert your `list` to a `set` first. There are 2 similar solutions, depending on whether you need ordered results.

**Ordered**

```
from itertools import combinations

productcode = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']

res_lst = sorted(map(sorted, combinations(set(productcode), 2)))

# [['apple', 'grape'], ['apple', 'orange'], ['grape', 'orange']]
```

I'm not sure what order you require, so I've sorted both *within* and *across* sublists, alphabetically in each case.

**Unordered**

If order is unimportant anywhere, then you need to use a `set` of `frozenset` items:

```
res_set = set(map(frozenset, combinations(set(productcode), 2)))

# {frozenset({'apple', 'orange'}),
#  frozenset({'grape', 'orange'}),
#  frozenset({'apple', 'grape'})}
```

This is because `set` items must be immutable; `frozenset` is an immutable version of `set`. This is one natural way to test whether a pair is in the set. For example:

```
{'orange', 'apple'} in res_set  # True
```

Another way is to use a set of alphabetically sorted tuples.

Comment: Thank you. Using "combinations" and keeping the sorting took me 20 seconds runtime, removing the sorting took me to 8 seconds (for 2113 distinct productcodes that I'm reading from a file). Can I get greedier than 8 secs?

Comment: @JubG, I can't see any obvious way, but it may be possible via `cython`, but this will be a more complex solution.